# Android Notification Not working on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm implementing local notification on Android and I have the problem that they are not appearing on Android 6.0 (Samsung S7).
I was searching for solutions, but I coulnd't find anything for this problem. I have the icon in the proper res/drawable folder, also I have defined a notification title, text, ringtone (raw folder) but it's not showing up...
There is my code:

```
    Context acontext = getApplicationContext();

    PackageManager pm = acontext.getPackageManager();
    Intent notificationIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(acontext.getPackageName());
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(acontext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    int notification_icon = acontext.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", acontext.getPackageName());
    int notificationID = 0;

    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(acontext)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Incoming text")
            .setSmallIcon(notification_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1, 1)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) acontext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + acontext.getPackageName() + "/raw/incoming");
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, noti);
```

Did anyone else experience this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: notification is working on lower version ?

Comment: Yes, it's working on Android 5.0

Comment: Does it show any kind of a message in the Logger?

Comment: There are no error messages or warnings if this is what you meant, and the method creating these notifications are always called, and the Notification object has been created.

Comment: Have you found the solution? @Tünde

Answer (score 3):

There are some changes in new notification. new `NotificationCompat.Builder(this)` is deprecated and need `NotificationChannel`for android oreo above. You can try this solution.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
        Intent ii = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), RootActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, ii, 0);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(verseurl);
        bigText.setBigContentTitle("Title");
        bigText.setSummaryText("Text in detail");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your Title");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Your text");
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: These new changes are for android 8.0 and higher, how these can work for android 6.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are various layers involved in showing notifications in Android, Please first check if this works for other devices of same OS version. Normally these kind of issues are device specific not OS specific, Also check notification logs [how to check notification logs in android ?](https://www.theverge.com/2018/10/19/18001608/android-notification-history-how-to-view)

If issue is device specific, following can be handy tips:

1. Check notifications not blocked for your app by device settings.
2. Check power settings blocking non-priority notifications.
3. If there are notifications in logs but not showing up, there can be some issue with your internal OS settings/configs. (believe me Android is not very clean OS)
4. If you can, try factory resetting your device. (In my case this worked)

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services must be enabled in order to receive push notifications on your Android device. If Google Play Services are enabled and the general troubleshooting steps have not resolved the issue, it may be necessary to reset the app. To reset the app, go to Settings → Apps → PagerDuty and tap Clear Data.

For Android 6.0 and newer, make sure the app is set as a prioritized app in priority mode.

For Android 6.0 and newer, check to see if the app is being silenced by Doze mode.

Comment: I have Play Services enabled. Also I'm receiving push notifications from other apps (like gmail or facebook...). Only my app's notifications are not showing up.

Answer (score -1):

Check the android version accordingly set the icon for > 6.0 and for other.For 6.0 version we need white background icon.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
 icon = R.mipmap.your_logo_for_Lolipop;
}else{
 icon = R.drawable.your_logo_for_Kitkat ;
}
```